# How to removechild in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code:

```
var star:Sprite = new Sprite();
for (var i:Number = 0; i<50; ++i) //check if sky contains star , remove them
{
     if (sky.contains(star)) //this "if" didnt work!
     {
        sky.removeChild(star);
     }
}
for (i= 0; i<50; ++i) //add new stars to sky
{
    star = new Sprite();
    star.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    star.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, ((Math.random() * 1.5) + 0.25));
    star.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth ;
    star.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    sky.addChild(star);
}
```

the 1st "if" didnt work and in 2nd "for" stars add to sky over previous stars! what is the correct code to remove previous stars?thanks

Comment: Use arrays instead of overriding the same variable over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Use this remove stars from the sky. It will remove all objects from sky.

```
 for (var i:Number = 0; i < sky.numchildren; ++i) 
    { 
            sky.removeChildAt(i);
    }
```

If you want to remove only stars from the sky , declare a new class for star

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i<sky.numchildren; ++i) 
{ 
        if(sky.getChildAt(i) is Star){
             sky.removeChildAt(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: You declare a new class `Star`, but you never use it. You first create a `new Star`, then you override the variable with `new Sprite`. Why?

Comment: I assumed the star is a sprite and the class extends Sprite. I justr copied the code from the questions and accidentally included. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

As @DodgerThud said in his comment, it's better to use an array to store your stars for this portion of your code and may be for others operations you will do / need in next steps, so you can do like this :

```
var star:Sprite,
    stars:Array = [],   // array to store our stars
    i:int;

for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++)
{
    Sprite(stars[i]).parent.removeChild(stars[i]);
}
stars = [];

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    star = new Sprite();
    star.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF);
    star.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, ((Math.random() * 1.5) + 0.25));
    star.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth ;
    star.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    stars.push(star);   // store your star into the stars array
    sky.addChild(star);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this code add 50 new stars to previous stars

Comment: @Fanous This is impossible, because I tested the code and it's working fine ! Try to add a trace after the second for loop : `trace(sky.numChildren);  // it gives always 50`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `while` loop instead of `if` here.

// that removes all the childs

```
while(sky.numChildren > 0){
  sky.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

// if you want to keep just 1 clip

```
while(sky.numChildren > 1){
      sky.removeChildAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't actually your sky is empty in this case but still on the stage

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to remove all stars from the sky and:

1. Sky is also a sprite or subclass of sprite
2. Your sky only contains stars and nothing else
3. You want to clear all stars from the sky and then add them back.

Hope this helps.

```
var stars:Array = new Array();

for(var i:int=0; i<sky.numChildren; ++i)    
{
    sky.removeChild(sky.getChildAt(i)); 
} 

if(stars.length == 0) //create stars if not created before 
{
    for (i= 0; i<50; ++i)
    {
        var star:Sprite = new Sprite();
        star.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        star.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, ((Math.random() * 1.5) + 0.25));
        star.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth ;
        star.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
        stars.push(star);
    }
} 
//add all stars created to sky 
for each(var _star:Sprite in stars) 
{
    sky.addChild(_star); 
}
```

Comment: I use your code and trace (sky.numChildren) , this is the result after few loops : 1/51/76/88/94/97/99/100/100/100/100

Comment: May you provide your code? are you working with Flash fla file or pure actionscript file?

Comment: the code is exactly your code ! Im working with flash cs6.